# Android CountDown timer on Finish not working on Android 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I am using a CountDown timer in an activity to keep a 2 min check for OTP validation, the problem is that code onFinish doesn't work on Android 9 and 8  devices. The App doesn't crash but there is no error. It works fine on Android 10 devices

```
private void startTimer(int noOfMinutes) {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(noOfMinutes, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            isCountDownRunning = true;

            // Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println("Long seconds= " + hms);
            textViewOTP.setText("OTP will expire in: " + hms); //set text
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            isCountDownRunning = false;

            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            countDownTimer = null; //set CountDownTimer to null

            textViewOTP.setText("OTP has expired"); //set text

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //   WaveLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Patient_OTP_Verification.this, Patient_Mobile_Registration.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    }.start();
}
```